# Local IIS unable to connect local database

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis-7, entity-framework-5

I am using a db from (localdb)\V11.0 server and able to connect successfully when using IIS express from VS2013, but when deployed in LocalIIS, it gives me an error below -

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.

In order to fix that I have updated `applicationHost.config` file as below

```
<add name="DefaultAppPool">
    <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
 </add>
```

Now, though database is not connected, it has displayed a home page, but all data-driven dropdown values are empty. I have also tried changing `Application pool` to `LocalSystem` but website unable connect db. Is there any specific area that I need to investigate?

Comment: What's the actual error message you're getting since you seem to be able to connect to the DB now?

Comment: I am going to edit my question.. after config updated, still not connected to database, however it has not shown any error and displayed home page but all dropdown values are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get local db running with IIS on my machine, I followed the guidance in [this msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx)

The solution that worked best for me was to configure IIS application pools to run as my windows user.

This is done via the IIS interface. In the "Application Pools" section, right click on one (or more) and choose "Advanced Settings". Choose "Identity" and "Custom" then enter your username and password.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if Application Pool / Local System has an account to access the database. There is also an option to user impersonate user https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158
 example:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```